# pytube, How to download private YouTube video?

Tags: python, pytube

I have code to download YouTube video, but it can not download private video link.Can someone help me how to modify code?

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8nlTw-SOMETHING')
yt.streams \
    .filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4') \
    .order_by('resolution') \
    .desc() \
    .first() \
    .download()')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey i used Pytube to create a Youtube MP3/MP4 downloader and had this problem, **you can not download private videos** if they are your videos c**hange them to public or at least unlisted**.

If you would like i can comment my github repository for my youtube downloader for you to see what i did or gain inspiration from it aswell